# PHP functions with MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, function

I'm making simple basketball stats plugin to wordpress, and I'm using dropdown list a lot. I wanted to make function but I don't know how to pass arguments to MySQL. Here's my code:

```
function dropDown($tab, $option, $text){
    $result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM tab');
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<option value=\"";
        echo $row['option'] . "\">" . $row['text'];
        echo "</option><br>";
    }
}
```

and I would like to use it like this:

```
dropDown("team", "team_id", "name");
```

I tried with different quotation marks, dots etc but it doesn't seem to work.

@edit
I know PHP syntax (some of it) and I know how to use it, but I don't know how to pass $variables to MySQL query, and that's my main problem.

Comment: I think you need to read up on your [PHP function syntax](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

Comment: RTFM? http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
function dropDown($team, $team_id, $name) {

  // use both three var where you want
  $result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM team');
     echo "<select>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch($result)){
        echo "<option value=\"";
        echo $row['team_id'] . "\">" . $row['name'];
        echo "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}

dropDown("team", "team_id", "name");
```